# Слитно или раздельно "не"

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Как верно написать подзаголовок "(Не)способные на любовь"? А в контексте: "Неспособные на любовь в принципе – люди с очень низким уровнем либидо"?

Answer (score 2):

Как верно? **Слитно**, [как у Розенталя](http://upravlenie.academic.ru/1289):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя… Слитно возможно **в первом примере**.

**Во втором** же я бы написал раздельно. Наличие наречия ***в принципе*** усиливает отрицание этой *способности*:

***Не способные** на любовь **в принципе** – люди…*